# How can I show the size of all files in my ~/.cache directory?

Tags: files, disk-usage, size

I want to get the size of all files in my `~/.cache` directory.

Comment: What's your definition of _cache files_? (Please [edit] your question to clarify this.)

Comment: `du -ach ~` will recursively show the size of all files and directories in `~`, execute it and let us know which ones you want to filter for

Comment: I need all files which starts with   /home/bzz/.cache

Comment: @Phil What part of "Please edit your question to clarify this" did you not understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
du -ch /home/bzz/.cache*
```

will give you the total size of all files which starts with `.cache` in `/home/bzz/`.